# The square root of -1 is not equal to the negative of itself?

Tags: complex-numbers

Could you help me with this? It's seriously wrong, but I cannot prove that it is wrong. Here is my problem:

Solve $-1^{1.5}$.

I used two ways:

A. Convert $-1^{1.5}$ to $-1^1 * -1^{0.5}$ then solve. The answer is $-i$.

B. Convert $-1^{1.5}$ to $\sqrt {-1^3}$ ($x^{y/z} = \root z \of {x^y} $) then solve. The answer should be $i$.

If $-i = i$, then $-1 = 1$.
Would you explain in which step was I wrong?

Comment: $i$ and $-i$ are different numbers. Both of them when squared give $-1$.

Comment: Using the rules of exponents on negatives bases means you really got to be cautious...

Comment: $\sqrt{-1^3} = \sqrt{(-1)\times(-1)\times(-1)} = -1\sqrt{-1} = -i$. Is this not the way we do the calculation? And moreover, $x^{y/z} \neq \sqrt[y]{x^z}$. Instead, $x^{y/z} = \sqrt[z]{x^y}$

Comment: Sorry! I accidentally exchanged those two variables y and z while typing.

Comment: Note that the square root of $-1$ is either positive or negative $i$. Picking the positive answer to any square root process is an arbitrary choice. With that in mind, both methods get both correct answers.

Comment: And of course, exponentiation on the complex plane is not one-to-one. With the above you didn't prove that $i = -i$

Comment: Oh, thanks, Kaynex. I totally forgot about those basic stuff.

Comment: @HyunsooKim not all exponent rules work equally well on all types of numbers, some need to be altered to work properly.

Answer (score 2):

Taking a non-integer power of a complex number may result in more than one answer. In your case, $-1 = e^{i (\pi + 2\pi k)}$, where $k$ is an integer. Consequently, $$(-1)^{1.5} = e^{i 3\pi/2 + 3i \pi k}=\left\{\begin{matrix} -i, & \text{for even $k$;} \\i, & \text{for odd $k$.}\end{matrix}\right.$$

Answer (score 1):

In the complex numbers $a^b$ is defined as $e^{b \log a}$ but the complex logarithm is multivalued.  For any $z \in \Bbb C, k\in \Bbb Z, e^{z+2k\pi i}=e^z$.  In the reals we take the square root sign to return the positive square root, which leads us to put $\pm$ signs in when we take a square root sometimes.  In the complex field the positive numbers are not defined, so $-1^{0.5}$ can be either $i$ or $-i$.  Similarly, $(-1)^{1.5}$ can be either $i$ or $-i$.